# C: Difference between the two array initializations

Tags: c, pointers

Why is there a difference between these two array initializations?

```
char *message = "HELLO";

if(message[0] == 'H'){
    // true
}
```

Ok, this works. But this doesn't:

```
char message[6] = "HELLO";

if(message[0] == 'H'){
    // false
}
```

Aren't they expressing the same thing?

Comment: They are. I am getting the expected behavior with gcc 4.8.2.

Comment: It appears that perhaps you gave an incorrect example. Both of those should and do evaluate to true (as well as `if ("HELLO"[0] == 'H')`).

Comment: it seems like an issue with avr-gcc (on embedded devices), sorry

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the first code fragment, `message` is a pointer to a read-only array of characters. You can modify the pointer (e.g. `++message` is fine), but you cannot modify what it points to (`message[0] = 'X'` invokes undefined behavior).

In the second code fragment, `message` is an array of characters with an initializer. You cannot modify the variable (`++message` is invalid), but you can modify the contents of the array (`message[0] = 'X'` is fine).

Also `sizeof(message)` is likely to be different.

They behave similarly when you simply access `message[0]`; that is, either you are wrong about your claimed behavior or your compiler has a very surprising bug.

But they are different things and behave differently in several ways, some of which I just enumerated.

Answer (score 0):

`"HELLO"` has the type `const char *`. But due to historical reasons this can be considered as a char *.

`char messagd[6]` is an array of characters on the stack. A different beast.

You need to use `strcpy` to populate that array